# Proof without words that $\tan ^{-1} 2-\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)=\cot ^{-1} 8$

Tags: trigonometry

After reading the book “Proof without words” written by Mr Roger B. Nelsen, I started to collect questions with proof without words.  When I encounter problems now, I’ll first try to find the proof without words. For this one, I found one myself and want to share it with you now.
[image]

Is it beautiful?
Have you got any other alternate proofs?  Share with us if you have any.

Comment: I'm willing to bet that something very close to this diagram works in the general case $\arctan u-\arctan v = \arctan\left(\dfrac{u-v}{1+uv}\right)$ — consider generalizing this to that case?

Comment: Good suggestion!

Comment: Yes, you are right! I have done it. You can read my proof below.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I don't know how I could have been able to add geometry images using LaTex in as answer

Comment: What I assume by **without words**: Means something that can be understood by the **simple geometry in the very first glance and not using backup formulas** because proves of formulas include *words*


Let me know if it's wordy, also I avoided to use
$$A(u)−A(v)=A(\frac{u-v}{1+uv})$$
and used ratios of triangles By A(x) I mean arctan(x) the old notation used in Ramanujan's lost notebooks

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Steven Stadnicki, I have just succeeded in completing a proof without words$$
\tan ^{-1} u-\tan ^{-1} v=\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{u-v}{1+u v}\right)
$$
by the following diagram:[image]

Answer (score -1):

\begin{align}\cot (\tan^{-1}(2)-\tan^{-1}(3/2))&= {1\over \tan{ (\tan^{-1}(2)-\tan^{-1}(3/2))}}\\
& = {1 +2(3/2)\over (2)-(3/2)}\\
&= {1+3\over 1/2}\\
&= 8\end{align}

Comment: No words.........

Comment: If anyone complains that this proof is too wordy, it at least doesn't contain text that isn't also in the OP's visual proof....